# shell script for oracle installation in linux

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, installation, centos7

I want to install oracle  12.2 in centos 7 and there is 10 machine in my environment.
is there any shell script for oracle installation in centos 7?

path is /home with default permission.

Thanks you!

Comment: Thanks for coming to Stack for your question.   This website is available to provide answers to specific coding questions.  Your question is not code specific and would be a "systems" question or possibly a "how to install" question.   Oracle has resources available for finding a solution to this type of question.  And so I would recommend closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the first one manually using the standard installer. Once that is done, the install also supports a "clone existing" function either on the same machine or a different one.  This ensure that the various inventory metadata details are captured, which is needed as well as the binaries in the ORACLE_BASE folder.

Examples on cloning and the steps needed are at:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ssdbi/cloning-an-oracle-home.html#GUID-494E59C3-C381-4A35-8ABE-F6E5DBF29032

Comment: Hey, Thanks for commenting.
but this process is time consuming and it need repeating task.  is there any other solution.